# IndexError: list index out of range. Can anyone help me out with this Python code ? Includes concepts of numpy and pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to Python and is working on the basic use of numpy and pandas. I am using VS Code as my source code editor.
The code is as follows :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

temp = np.random.randint(low = 20, high = 100, size = [20,])
name = np.random.choice(['A','Python','Excel','B'], 20)
random = np.random.choice([10,11,12,13,14], 20)

a = list(zip(temp, name, random))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = a, columns = [temp, name, random])
print(df)
```

And the output I am getting is :

```
(work) PS C:\DEV> & c:/DEV/work/Scripts/python.exe c:/DEV/Num.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/DEV/Num.py", line 9, in <module>
(work) PS C:\DEV> & c:/DEV/work/Scripts/python.exe c:/DEV/Num.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/DEV/Num.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = a, columns = [temp, name, random])
  File "C:\DEV\work\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 462, in __init__
    mgr = arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\DEV\work\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 87, in 
arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "C:\DEV\work\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1694, in 
create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
  File "C:\DEV\work\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1745, in form_blocks
    v = arrays[name_idx]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me out?
I am expecting a Dataframe list of random values, specified by the above hardcoded values in my code.

Comment: maybe `columns=['temp', 'name', 'random']`?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Never guessed it could be time this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is with this line - the columns list should be a list of strings. At the moment, you try to assign the lists themselves to the column names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = a, columns = ['temp', 'name', 'random'])
```